# BarCode Scanner and Python

Tags: python, input, barcode, background-process

I have a barcode scanner ([Keyence BL-N70UBE](http://www.keyence.com/products/vision/barcode/bl/models/bl-n70ube/index.jsp)) that behaves like a keyboard input.  I'd like to have a python script that runs in the background and only when the barcode scanner reads anything in, it will kickoff a process to control a windows application (like with PyWinAuto, or something).

The problem I'm having is that I seem to need to have the console open for Python to accept the input as actually being inputted.  Also, the other problem is that it has no way of differentiating the barcode scanner and the keyboard.  Is there a better way to implement this?

```
input_data0 = raw_input('waiting for keyboard input ...\n')
input_data1 = raw_input('waiting for keyboard input ...\n')
input_data2 = raw_input('waiting for keyboard input ...\n')
input_data3 = raw_input('waiting for keyboard input ...\n')
input_data4 = raw_input('waiting for keyboard input ...\n')

print input_data0
print input_data1
print input_data2
print input_data3
print input_data4
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture input one level earlier at the level of individual keys.

Pay attention to start character (most barcodes readers have that configurable, typically on for 2D barcodes and often off for 3D barcodes).

Keep a timer, if a character is not start of barcode sequence or more than threshold time has passed since last character, assumer it's not part of barcode and let it though.

Check e.g. https://github.com/marcinlawnik/pykeylogger-fork how to intercept keyboard before it hits the system.